# Database mirroring is limited to an original database

Tags: sql-server-2008

Database mirroring is limited to an original database and how many mirror copies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, database mirroring works from one principle server to one mirror server. Only one mirror copy can be used. For multiple readable replicas, consider [AlwaysOn Availability Groups](http://www.brentozar.com/sql/sql-server-alwayson-availability-groups/), introduced in SQL Server 2012 Enterprise Edition.